# I am trying to send email from a FORM using PHP, but i receive the details without the From email Address

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I am trying to send email from a FORM, but i receive the details without the FROM email Address, help to rectify the issue.

```
/* HTML FORM CODE */

<form action="contact.php" method="post">
Name:<br><input type="text" name="name"><br>
From:<br><input type="text" name"from"><br>
Request:<br><textarea type="text" name="request"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="send">
</form>
/* HTML FORM CODE */

/* PHP SEND EMAIL CODE */
<?php
$name=$_POST['name'];
$from=$_POST['from'];
$request=$_POST['request'];

$to="skks1981@gmail.com";
$subject=$request;
$body=<<<EMAIL
Hai My name is $name

My email is $from

$request

EMAIL;
$header:$from;
mail($to,$subject,$body,$header);
echo "Message Sent";
?>

/* PHP SEND EMAIL CODE */
```

Note: In From part i receive unknown or admin@khatamband.com email address.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this $header:

```
$header = "From: {$from}";
```

and not

```
$header:$from;
```

Comment: @StylerKishore Have you send the form and fill in all fields? In your code you don't have any if and you try to send mail each time